# Is there any Newton Method solver in Matlab

Tags: matlab, newtons-method

I know how to program Newton method in Matlab, but I am still curious if there is any built-in  Newton solver in Matlab?(Or bisection method?)

Comment: I think you may be interested in [`fzero`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) and [`roots`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/roots.html) functions. `fzero` is not purely bisection method, but a hybrid algo containing bisection also.

Comment: Just note that `bisection` differs from Newton's method...

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is.

It is called [`fsolve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html), and it is part of the [Optimization Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/index.html). You can choose the algorithm to be either trust-region-dogleg (default), trust-region-reflective or Levenberg-Marquardt, and according to the documentation:

> The trust-region-reflective algorithm is a subspace trust-region method and is based on the interior-reflective Newton method described in [1] and [2].

<sup>For your convenience, the references are:

[1] Coleman, T.F. and Y. Li, "An Interior, Trust Region Approach for Nonlinear Minimization Subject to Bounds," *SIAM Journal on Optimization*, Vol. 6, pp. 418-445, 1996.

[2] Coleman, T.F. and Y. Li, "On the Convergence of Reflective Newton Methods for Large-Scale Nonlinear Minimization Subject to Bounds," *Mathematical Programming*, Vol. 67, Number 2, pp. 189-224, 1994.</sup>

As stated in the comments, if you want a solver that uses the [bisection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method), there is [`fzero`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html), which the documentation states to use a combination of bisection, secant, and inverse quadratic interpolation methods.

Comment: Aren't "Newton's method" as used in optimization and "Newton's method" as used in rootfinding two different things? Related, yes, but different; see [NM in optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization) vs. [NM in rootfinding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method).

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis +1 for a good question :) However, isn't `fsolve` essentially a "solver" that uses NM? That is, it finds roots, doesn't it?

Comment: Hmyes...but `lsqnonlin` for example also uses `trust-region-reflective`, however, *that* has little to do with rootfinding, but everything with optimization :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis True, but I'd argue that it is a matter of context. NM in optimization is just a specialized version of NM in rootfinding... Anyway, I feel that I'm stretching my answer just to make it sound right :)